# How do I turn the beep slash bell off in cygwin?

Tags: bash, cygwin

The system beep/bell happens frequently (ie, when I type a few letters then type tab to autocomplete when there are a few options).

How can I turn this off?

I googled it and tried:

```
set bell-style none (the command went through but nothing changed)
```

and

```
setterm -blength 0 (got a bash command not found)
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you typed those at a bash prompt, that's not where either one goes. See Emerick Rogul's answer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Add `set bell-style none` to `.inputrc` in your home directory.  You need to start a new shell for this to take effect; that may be why your test didn't work.

Comment: I've had this in .inputrc for some time now (across reboots even) and I still get the bell. Both in mintty *and* xterm.

Comment: Great! I have to do this on every account that I ssh to. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

The default terminal `mintty` has built-in options to control the terminal bell.

1. Right-click on the background and click "Options..."
2. Select the "Terminal" section.
3. Change the "Bell" dropdown to "none"

Note: Here you can also enable or disable the visible bell (terminal flashing) and to highlight the taskbar icon on a bell ring.

Comment: This is definitely the _best_answer...  Using the answer from @Emerick works...  Until you ssh somewhere...

Comment: @Lucas: You can `set bell-style none` on the machine you ssh to as well...

Answer (score 6):

Cut the wire to your speaker.  :-)

Comment: This is the more portable option, since it works with any shell. ;-)

Comment: And next time, get a motherboard that connects your speaker via a header, so that you can just unplug it.

Comment: You could also poke your ear drums with a needle. That works for all shells and platforms as well.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution that doesn't seem to be mentioned here is:

1. Right click on the header of the Cygwin window and chose `Options...`:

[image]

2. In the options menu, under the `Terminal` tab, choose "no beep":

[image]

This should take effect immediately without having to restart Cygwin.

Comment: Good answer but this solution *was* posted (albeit without the nice screenshots) a few years previously: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980567/1640661

Comment: Ah, you're right. I guess I must have just read the accepted answer, and missed that one was explaining the same as I was :)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a series of beeps when I would cat a particular file.  The above tips did not silence the bell.  In my case, the beeps were due to bullet points that had been copy/pasted into the file.  Replacing the bullets with dashes stopped the beeping.

Answer (score 0):

Use mintty. Among many other advantages over the usual console, the bell is off by default.

Comment: Care to elaborate on how to use mintty and what advantages it offers?

Answer (score 0):

Path to '.inputrc:

```
'C:\cygwin64\home\<username>\.inputrc
```